# dup() followed by close() from multiple threads or processes

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, multiprocess

My program does the following in chronological order

1. The program is started with root permissions.
2. Among other tasks, A file only readable with root permissions is `open()`ed.
3. Root privileges are dropped.
4. Child processes are spawned with `clone()` and the `CLONE_FILES | CLONE_FS | CLONE_IO` flags set, which means that while they use separate regions of virtual memory, they share the same file descriptor table (and other IO stuff).
5. All child processes `execve()` their own programs (the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag is not used).
6. The original program terminates.

Now I want every spawned program to read the contents of the aforementioned file, but after they all have read the file, I want it to be closed (for security reasons).

One possible solution I'm considering now is having a step 3a where the fd of the file is `dup()`licated once for every child process, and each child gets its own fd (as an `argv`). Then every child program would simply `close()` their fd, so that after all fds pointing to the file are `close()`d the "actual file" is closed.

But does it work that way? And is it safe to do this (i.e. is the file really closed)? If not, is there another/better method?

Comment: If both the parent and the children all close their fd, then the file is closed. Is there any reason to use `clone`? A simple `fork` would exhibit much the same behavior, I think.

Comment: `If both the parent and the children all close their fd, then the file is closed.` That would be good news, thanks. `Is there any reason to use clone? A simple fork would exhibit much the same behavior, I think.` True, but the reason I use `clone()` is related to performance: all child programs need to handle the same really large set of sockets (through `epoll`). Sharing the fd table avoids unnecessary overhead. The reason I mention that in the question, is because I'm not 100% that this detail is irrelevant.

Comment: Is it an option to read(/parse) the file in the parent process and store the result in memory shared with `mmap` as step 3a? That would skip the issue of communicating the fd to the child processes and adhere to the principle of dropping privileges as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, I considered that, but because the content of the file is sensitive (an SSL private key), storing it in shared memory seems like a bad idea to me considering that that memory would be accessible by other processes (at least for a very short time), since the shared memory would need to be created *after* dropping root (or else the `execve()`d children won't be able to access it).

Comment: I don't quite follow. The fd is now also visible by other processes (the children). I understand your predicament, but it seems that in your current setup, no matter how it's implemented, you'll have to share a secret with the child processes and trust them to wipe it before executing a different program.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, if I used shared memory, won't that memory be also accessible by processes other than the children (I can't use `MAP_PRIVATE` because of the `execve()` calls)? Or are you saying that's true for file descriptors too?

Comment: Ehm, you're right, thinko. You'd have to unmap before the exec, just like you have to `close` now.

Comment: @larsmans I've added a preliminary answer (and a +1 to your first comment because it got me thinking in the right direction (probably)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `dup()` as I suggested above is probably just fine, I've now --a day after asking this SO question-- realized that there is a nicer way to do this, at least from the point of view of thread safety.

All `dup()`licated file descriptors point to the same same file position indicator, which of course means you run into trouble when multiple threads/processes might simultaneously try to change the file position during read operations (even if your own code does so in a thread safe way, the same doesn't necessarily go for libraries you depend on).

So wait, why not just call `open()` multiple times (once for every child) on the needed file before dropping root? From the manual of `open()`:

> A call to open() creates a new open file description, an entry in the system-wide table of open files. This entry records the file offset and the file status flags (modifiable via the fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation). A file descriptor is a reference to one of these entries; this reference is unaffected if pathname is subsequently removed or modified to refer to a different file. The new open file description is  initially not shared with any other process, but sharing may arise via fork(2).

Could be used like this:

```
int fds[CHILD_C];
for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_C; i++) {
    fds[i] = open("/foo/bar", O_RDONLY);
    // check for errors here
}
drop_privileges();
// etc
```

Then every child gets a reference to one of those fds through `argv` and does something like:

1. `FILE *stream = fdopen(atoi(argv[FD_STRING_I]), "r")`
2. read whatever needed from the `stream`
3. `fclose(stream)` (this also closes the underlying file descriptor)

Disclaimer: According to a bunch of tests I've run this is indeed safe and sound. I have however only tested `open()`ing with **O_RDONLY**. **Using O_RDWR or O_WRONLY may or may not be safe**.